# ElMAH Error Logging using Gmail?

Tags: c#, .net, elmah

I have used ELMAH in the past using an hMailServer, but unfortunately, I am working on a project where I do not have a dedicatd mail server, so I have been just sending test emails from a gmail account  I have setup.

Additionally, I am going to be adding ELMAH error logging into the application. I was wondering if ELMAH will support using GMAIL as its method for sending emails?

**EDIT** It does seem that there is a possibility that this will work according to the following article:

[Elmah Via Gmail](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/05/21/163350.aspx)

Comment: You answered your own question. Post your answer and accept it ( note: this is usually not possible immediately )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that there is a way to do this. I came across a blog that talks about it here:

[ELMAH Error Logging Via Gmail](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/05/21/163350.aspx)